# VNC (display :0) through SSH with Arch

Tags: arch-linux, ssh-tunneling, vnc, sshd

I want to share the display :0 of my Computer runngin Arch with my Android phone.

What I have tried:
I connected to the computer via ssh and forwarded the VNC port. I used `x0vncserver` of the `tigervnc` package. Everything worked fine except the fact that the VNC server was available in the hole network.

But I only want to tunnle it through SSH. The tool `vncserver` has the option `-localhost`. In x0vncserver I could not find anything similar.

Answer (score 1):

Now I found the solution. The alternative `x11vnc` allows to use the `-localhost` parameter.
The complete command is:

```
x11vnc -display :0 -localhost
```